# Ratchet : How to use both chat and push notifications on the same server

Tags: php, websocket

i would like to use on the same server both applications "chat" and 'push notifications" comming from the tutorial of ratchet (http://socketo.me) 
- "Hello world" (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)
- "push integration" with ZMQ .
each application works well , i run chat-server.php (for chat) and push-server.php (for push integration) . But when i open two cmd window and run both it does not working . It is maybe a stupid question , but i'm a beginner in this field .

find below the code of both executable

---

chat-server.php :

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

---

push-server.php :

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help . let me know If you need more informations

Comment: Try changing one of the servers to another port like 8081.

Comment: Hi, got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate files, **chat-server.php** and **push-server.php**, but you can't listen to the same port from two different files. You'll have to change one of them. You can keep **push-server.php**'s port as `8080` and change **chat-server.php**'s port to `3000` (for example):

```php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer; use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    3000
);

$server->run();
```

---

If you'd like to use a single server file, it's quite simple, all you have to do is add one line from **chat-server.php** to **push-server.php** (I wrote a comment next to it). So your final file would look something like this:

```php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new MyApp\Chat(), // This is the line added
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Don't add anything else from **server.php** such as the `use ...;` lines

Make sure you have separate files **/src/MyApp/Chat.php** and **/src/MyApp/Pusher.php** with the classes `Chat` and `Pusher` respectively.

Now when you run:

```
$ php push-server.php
```

It will perform the tasks that **server.php** did.